# Custom css color in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have that css :

```
.black-text{
     font-size: 11px;
     color: black;
     margin: 10px 0 0 25px;
 }
```

in chrome everything is ok but in firefox color and font-size don't work.. but margin and other things works  ??

```
  <div><span className="black-text"> {this.state.messageNextPeriod}</span></div>
```

Other

```
table.scroll thead tr {
    background-color: #337ab7;
    color: white;
    /* fallback */
    width: 97%;
    /* minus scroll bar width */
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 16px);
    width:    -moz-calc(100% - 16px);
    width:         calc(100% - 16px);
}
```

and

```
<table className="table scroll">
```

Comment: Tested size in firefox and got no errors.

Comment: You don't mention `background-color` in your question...

Comment: Ohh sry guys my big mistake .. i add my custom css in bootstrap css file and that was the problem i move my css in my file and everything go perfect :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firefox inspector, select the element you want to inspect and then go to the Computed tab. There you can see from which css rule the element is enheriting those properties.

[image]